# Comparing two image in IOS 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

Earlier we use to compare two images by using isEquals(==) if both image object are using [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"].
But in IOS 8 it is not working. 
is there any specific reason for that or we can do the same??

Comment: Depends what you mean by comparing.  The `==` operator will tell you if two `UIImage` instances are the same, however if you want to compare pixels then that's a different matter.  Please be more specific.

Comment: @Droppy Obviously comparing two image object not by the pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never and never use `==` to compare objects equality.

Here is a simple method, which will resolve your issue.

```
- (BOOL)image:(UIImage *)aImage1 equalsTo:(UIImage *)aImage2
{
    NSData *img1Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(aImage1, 1.0);
    NSData *img2Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(aImage1, 1.0);
    return [img1Data isEqualToData:img2Data];
}
```